# Deep Sort uses a lot of CPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, yolo

I'm creating a software that reads multiple cameras in different threads with OpenCV and then process them in the main thread using YOLOv4 Tensorflow model. This way my GPU is running on around 40% capacity and my CPU cores are all around 30-40% as well in the gnome-system-monitor.

However, when I integrate Deep sort, GPU stays around the same on usage but CPU load goes to 100% on every core.

My question is, is this normal? Does Deep sort run mostly on CPU?

I'm initializing and running deep sort just like in this repo file:
https://github.com/theAIGuysCode/yolov4-deepsort/blob/9e745bfb3ea5e7c7505cb11a8e8654f5b1319ad9/object_tracker.py#L48

Using:

- Ubuntu 18.04
- Python 3.8
- Tensorflow 2.3.1
- OpenCV Python 4.4.0.44
- CUDA 10.1.243, cuDNN 7.6.5 with driver 418.152

Specs workstation laptop:

- NVIDIA RTX Quadro 5000
- Intel® Xeon(R) E-2276M CPU @ 2.80GHz × 12
- 32 GB Memory

Answer (score 1):

No. It is not normal. It is a bug. Check my repo for a fix

https://github.com/mikel-brostrom/Yolov5_DeepSort_Pytorch/issues/48

You need to add limits to the CPUs used by your HPC libraries like this:

```py
# limit the number of cpus used by high performance libraries
import os
os.environ["OMP_NUM_THREADS"] = "1"
os.environ["OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS"] = "1"
os.environ["MKL_NUM_THREADS"] = "1"
os.environ["VECLIB_MAXIMUM_THREADS"] = "1"
os.environ["NUMEXPR_NUM_THREADS"] = "1"
```

Comment: Hi! If i were to run it as a separate thread, where could I put these limiters ? In the thread.py itself ? Or in the main python script ?

Comment: I just ran Yolov5 and StrongSORT on a single thread. The execution time for StrongSORT was ~1.5secs with Osnetx25. In a process it achieved 0.02. So I wouldn’t recommend it.

Comment: that is a very significant difference in the execution time ! What is the reason for that difference ?

Comment: Most certainly because the single thread needs to handle all the data loading, both to Yolo and DeepSORT and then run the association process. A process would have multiple threads handling the whole process.

Comment: could splitting the YOLO and deepSORT portions into its individual threads help ? YOLO gets 1, deepSORT gets 1, association gets 1 for eg. Could multiprocessing be used instead ? Although there's some kind of GUI for how i am doing it

Comment: Maybe. But a single thread for everything, I know for a fact, is way to slow

Answer (score 0):

in _cosine_distance,  numpy arrays should declare dtype.

```
if not data_is_normalized:
    a = np.asarray(a) / np.linalg.norm(a, axis=1, keepdims=True)
    b = np.asarray(b) / np.linalg.norm(b, axis=1, keepdims=True)
```

change to:

```
if not data_is_normalized:
    a = np.array(a, dtype=np.float128) / np.linalg.norm(a, axis=1, keepdims=True)
    b = np.array(b, dtype=np.float128) / np.linalg.norm(b, axis=1, keepdims=True)
```